# Service Account Credentials not Sharing Spreadsheet to Business Account

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

*New to Google API:* I have the following function where I am trying to create a new spreadsheet with a dataframe in Google Sheets. When I go to share it with myself, it does not error out, but at the same time the new spreadsheet does not appear to be shared with me (it's not shown in docs.google.com/spreadsheets) - any idea why?

```
def create_insert_sheets(nm_sheet, email_share, type_role, df):
    gc = create_credentials()
    
    sh = gc.create(nm_sheet)
    sh.share(email_share, perm_type='user', role=type_role)
    
    ## 
    
    update_spreadsheet(0, sh.id, df)
    return sh

create_insert_sheets("api_test_create", ["my-service-account@kebasic=basu-3321113.iam.gserviceaccount.com","myemail@domain.com"], "owner", df_grade)
```

Comment: The file is probably being created on the service accounts drive account.

Comment: Exactly, so I have to authenticate with the Service Account to access Google API, but then those credentials are automatically being used to create the new Sheet, which then posts it to the Service Account's drive instead of my normal email. How would I correct this?

Comment: TBH its working as intended this is why service accounts have their own drive account.  However  If your intention is to have it created on your own drive account then you should create a directory on your personal drive account.  Share that directory with the service account.   Then have the service account create the file in that directory.

Comment: My end goal is to create a file and share it with my project team (8 people in my domain), and put it in the team's existing Google Drive... is this not the correct process to go through?

Comment: Is this a google workspace team drive you are talking about?  If so the service account granted the proper access to your domain account should be able to upload directly to that directory.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Have a look at this [delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)  I can help you alter the code for drive if this is what your looking for.